# Solidify Modifier going in all directions

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, artifacts

I was trying to create a different version of a stylized archway.  I used a couple of bezier curves to get the basic shape then borrowed some of the shapes from the original archway.  I got everything lined up, then joined the mesh created from the curves to the shapes from the archway.  Then I painstakingly went thru and connected the shapes to the curve and then used F to fill them in. Then I removed the original shapes by separating as I wanted holes there and tried to solidify the results.  Oh lordy, I did something very wrong somewhere because this is not what I was expecting.  In the [video](https://i.gyazo.com/6f2985ad6ee776905e078c01bd5ae84b.gif), I show my mesh and what it does and then the original exhibiting the desired behavior.

[image]

Comment: Please add a picture displaying the problem and modifier settings or a blend file.

Comment: I attached the link to the gif which shows it.https://gyazo.com/6f2985ad6ee776905e078c01bd5ae84b

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this mesh is it's mb its topology in order to fix that,  first go into edit mode and select all faces and then press shift+N to calculate normals, then try pressing alt+M and selecting merge by distance for removing double, if that still doesn't solve the problem then apply a remedy modifier above solidify (you even remedy manually or by some other add-on).  Try these one by one or all at the same time.